# power + operator for binary

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

What is the specific definition for power $+$ operator in automata theory? For example, when $x$ is a binary what does it mean that $x = 0^+$. Does it mean that x is a string with at least one $0$?

Comment: Yes, $0^+ := 00^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an alphabet $\Sigma$ the *Kleene star* $\Sigma^*$ is defined as the language containing all words that can be constructed from $\Sigma$.

The *Kleene plus* is defined as $\Sigma^*$ without the empty word:

$\Sigma^+ := \Sigma^* \setminus \{\varepsilon\}$